# Isotope - combination buttons and UI slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am trying to get Isotope plugin to filter with both cobination buttons and a UI slider but not sure how to go about doing it.

Can any one help me to acheve this.

Here is a link to my problem [code pen test case](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adjzNW)

```
<h1>Isotope - combination filters</h1>

<div class="filters">

  <div class="ui-group">
    <h3>Color</h3>
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="color">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">any</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".red">red</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".blue">blue</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".yellow">yellow</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-group">
    <h3>Size</h3>
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="size">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">any</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".small">small</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".wide">wide</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".big">big</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".tall">tall</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-group">
    <h3>Shape</h3>
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="shape">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">any</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".round">round</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".square">square</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sliders" data-filter-group="features">
    <div class="noUi-target noUi-ltr noUi-horizontal noUi-background" id="slider-range"></div>
    <span class="val" id="slider-range-value"></span>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="color-shape small round red">180.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape small round blue">195.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape small round yellow">202.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape small square red">235.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape small square blue">240.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape small square yellow">250.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape wide round red">255.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape wide round blue">275.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape wide round yellow">285.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape wide square red">290.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape wide square blue">295.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape wide square yellow">300.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape big round red">300.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape big round blue">300.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape big round yellow">300.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape big square red">300.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape big square blue">180.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape big square yellow">180.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape tall round red">180.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape tall round blue">180.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape tall round yellow">255.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape tall square red">255.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape tall square blue">255.00</div>
  <div class="color-shape tall square yellow">255.00</div>
</div>




$( function() {

  // filter functions
  var filterFns = {
    greaterThan50: function() {
      var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
      return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50.00;
    },
    even: function() {
      var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
      return parseInt( number, 10 ) % 2 === 0;
    }
  };

  // init Isotope
  var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.color-shape',
    filter: function() {
      var isMatched = true;
      var $this = $(this);

      for ( var prop in filters ) {
        var filter = filters[ prop ];
        // use function if it matches
        filter = filterFns[ filter ] || filter;
        // test each filter
        if ( filter ) {
          isMatched = isMatched && $(this).is( filter );
        }
        // break if not matched
        if ( !isMatched ) {
          break;
        }
      }
      return isMatched;
    }
  });

  // store filter for each group
  var filters = {};

  $('#filters').on( 'click', '.button', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // get group key
    var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
    var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
    // set filter for group
    filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
    // arrange, and use filter fn
    $container.isotope('arrange');
  });

  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });

});



    * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* ---- button ---- */

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1.0em;
  background: #EEE;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0), hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2) );
  color: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #8CF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
  color: #222;
}

.button:active,
.button.is-checked {
  background-color: #28F;
}

.button.is-checked {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

/* ---- button-group ---- */

.button-group:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.button-group .button {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.button-group .button:first-child { border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em; }
.button-group .button:last-child { border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0; }

/* ---- isotope ---- */

.grid {
  background: #EEE;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ui group */

.ui-group {
  display: inline-block;
}

.ui-group h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.ui-group .button-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

/* color-shape */

.color-shape {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.color-shape.round {
  border-radius: 35px;
}

.color-shape.big.round {
  border-radius: 75px;
}

.color-shape.red { background: red; }
.color-shape.blue { background: blue; }
.color-shape.yellow { background: yellow; }

.color-shape.wide, .color-shape.big { width: 150px; }
.color-shape.tall, .color-shape.big { height: 150px; }




/* Functional styling for range slider;
 * These styles are required for noUiSlider to function.
 * You don't need to change these rules to apply your design.
 */
.noUi-target,
.noUi-target * {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none; 
-ms-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.noUi-target {
    position: relative;
    direction: ltr;
    width: 62%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.noUi-base {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; /* Fix 401 */
}
.noUi-origin {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.noUi-handle {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.noUi-stacking .noUi-handle {
/* This class is applied to the lower origin when
   its values is > 50%. */
    z-index: 10;
}
.noUi-state-tap .noUi-origin {
-webkit-transition: left 0.3s, top 0.3s;
    transition: left 0.3s, top 0.3s;
}
.noUi-state-drag * {
    cursor: inherit !important;
}

/* Painting and performance;
 * Browsers can paint handles in their own layer.
 */
.noUi-base {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

/* Slider size and handle placement;
 */
.noUi-horizontal {
    height: 18px;
}
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle {
    width: 35px;
    height: 26px;
    left: -17px;
    top: -5px;
}
.noUi-vertical {
    width: 18px;
}
.noUi-vertical .noUi-handle {
    width: 35px;
    height: 26px;
    left: -6px;
    top: -5px;
}

/* Styling;
 */
.noUi-background {
    background: #EEE linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #f0f0f0;
}
.noUi-connect {
    background: #3FB8AF;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.45);
-webkit-transition: background 450ms;
    transition: background 450ms;
}
.noUi-origin {
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.noUi-target {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #F0F0F0, 0 3px 6px -5px #BBB;
}
.noUi-target.noUi-connect {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.45), 0 3px 6px -5px #BBB;
}

/* Handles and cursors;
 */
.noUi-draggable {
    cursor: w-resize;
}
.noUi-vertical .noUi-draggable {
    cursor: n-resize;
}
.noUi-handle {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #7D64B1;
    cursor: grab;
}
.noUi-active {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) inset;
    cursor: grabbing;       
}

/* Handle stripes;
 */
.noUi-handle:before,
.noUi-handle:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 14px;
    width: 1px;
    background: #E8E7E6;
    left: 14px;
    top: 6px;
}
.noUi-handle:after {
    left: 19px;
}
.noUi-vertical .noUi-handle:before,
.noUi-vertical .noUi-handle:after {
    width: 14px;
    height: 1px;
    left: 6px;
    top: 14px;
}
.noUi-vertical .noUi-handle:after {
    top: 17px;
}

/* Disabled state;
 */
[disabled].noUi-connect,
[disabled] .noUi-connect {
    background: #B8B8B8;
}
[disabled].noUi-origin,
[disabled] .noUi-handle {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.val{
    margin: 9px 0px 0px;
  width: 8%;
  display: block;
}

.color-shape{
  text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

If any one can help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s give it a try. [See my demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/73238e7835570ac86352d0a4e4c7a091)

The trick is to use a [filter function for Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html#functions). Rather than changing the filter, we can change the values used in the filter logic. For this demo, we have two values: the `buttonFilter` and the `sliderValue`. I’ve set the filter function to check if the item matches the `buttonFilter` AND has a text value that is greater than or equal to the `sliderValue`.

```
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

$(document).ready( function() {

  var sliderValue = 180;

  // create the slider;
  var rangeSlider = document.getElementById('slider-range');

  noUiSlider.create(rangeSlider, {
    start: [ 180 ],
    range: {
      'min': [  180 ],
      'max': [ 300 ]
    }
  });

  // create the slider range value;
  var rangeSliderValueElement = document.getElementById('slider-range-value');

  rangeSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    rangeSliderValueElement.innerHTML = values[handle] + " cm";
  });


  // store filter for each group
  var buttonFilters = {};
  var buttonFilter = '*';

  // init Isotope
  var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.color-shape',
    // use filter function
    filter: function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var isMinSize = parseFloat( $this.text() ) >= sliderValue;
      return $this.is( buttonFilter ) && isMinSize;
    }
  });

  $('.filters').on( 'click', '.button', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // get group key
    var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
    var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
    // set filter for group
    buttonFilters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
    // combine filters
    buttonFilter = concatValues( buttonFilters ) || '*';
    console.log( buttonFilter )
    // set filter for Isotope
    $grid.isotope();
  });

  // filter isotope on slider set
  rangeSlider.noUiSlider.on( 'set', function( textValues, handle, values ) {
    sliderValue = values[ handle ];
    $grid.isotope();
  });

  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });

});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues( obj ) {
  var value = '';
  for ( var prop in obj ) {
    value += obj[ prop ];
  }
  return value;
}
```

Comment: This is really close to what I'm looking for as well. But I need it to work with a range slider that has a min max value e.g. height between 190-220. I found a working solution for the range filters http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/nbfhy but could not get it to work with the standard combination filters. Any chance you could modify the above example to work with a min/max range slider?

Comment: Actually I think I finally figured it out, spent a whole day on the weekend not being able to do it. I guess a good nights sleep helps. 
https://codepen.io/lifeonlars/pen/yaaOZy